# Something is messing up with my keyboard and mouse. How to find what is causing this problem?

Tags: linux, debian, troubleshooting

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (used as OS of my notebook)

The problem: Sometimes following things start to happen. The computer stops adequately reacting on hotkeys, as if one key was already pressed and kept pressed. And when I try to input text keys become "sticky", meaning that the symbol keeps being printed for some time, as if I were holding the key longer than I really did. The backspace key stops working, instead of erasing symbols it starts printing nonsense that includes symbol "]". When at this stage I switched to tty2 (Ctrl-Alt-F2, this works only if I try to switch early enough, problem with hotkeys becomes worse with time) and tried to log in as a root in order to view processes I failed. Keys were "sticky", and instead of latin letters they were printing nonsense with "]". If I didn't switch to tty2 then the whole thing would progress to its final stage, my mouse cursor would start running away in the left down corner. And I would be forced to forcibly shut down my computer.

Maybe it's just a coincidence, but I noticed that this whole thing happens only when both Firefox and Skype are running at the same time. I use the latest versions of both of them, by the way. There are only 3 addons on my Firefox that were turned on and I trust all of them: "uBlock origin", "Reddit Enhancement Suite", "Official Media Bias Fact Check Icon" (this is addon of site mediabiasfactcheck.com). All these times (the whole thing happened 3 times already) following sites were pinned: kissanimefree.xyz, youtube.com, smackjeeves.com, translate.google.com. Flash plugin is enabled with some dark magic on my Firefox Quantum, but it's both outdated and flash content is unsandboxed, but in order to run flash content I need to manually approve it.

Here is the output of "ps aux" for time when I was writting this post: https://textuploader.com/1h7ud

Comment: firefox fork many thread depending on site, even gmail.com, while `ps aux` will show 1(about 10 here) firefox process, `ps -L -p <firefox_pid>` might show you more.

Comment: @Archemar Did it, do you see anything suspicous? https://textuploader.com/1h2oy

Comment: just too many of them, I had my ubuntu 20 frozen when browsing either gmail or wowhead.com with flashy ad, I manage to log via ssh, kill firefox and everything came back to normal.